# why is host missing from my http request header fields?

Tags: http, go, httprequest, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I'm printing out all the headers and I get:

```
map[Cookie:[_ga=GA1.2.843429125.1462575405] User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0
(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4] Accept-Language:[en-us] 
Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate] Connection:[keep-alive] 
Accept:[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8]]
```

which means my browser is sending "Cookie", "User-Agent", "Accept-Language", "Accept-Encoding", "Connection", and "Accept" but there is no "Host" value.

How can I get my https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting working without this value?

I'm using https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin

Comment: Is this an HTTP/1.x or an HTTP/2 request?

Comment: http/1.x not http2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It stated on Golang http docs :

> For incoming requests, the Host header is promoted to the Request.Host
>   field and removed from the Header map.

So you can get the host by access

> http.Request.Host

Check here for details : https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Comment: Thanks for the help!  So annoying they don't treat this as a normal http header.  It's silent and difficult to figure out, until you find the right answer online.